# Using Contractions and Conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions, contractions

I'm wondering about starting a sentence with a contraction while use a coordinating conjunction. Here is an example:

> I'm sorry you're hungry, Adam, and would like to feed you.

Would this sentence be correct since the contraction doesn't make sense with the second clause? Or would it need to be two separate sentences? For example:

> I'm sorry you're hungry, Adam. I would like to feed you.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I think they are quiet informal

Answer (score 1):

The first version of the sentence is fine as is.  It means ***I am** sorry you're hungry, Adam, and **I** would like to feed you.* The connector *and* is very neutral, but works fine.

The second version is not wrong, but it gives a choppy feeling with no connection. The result sounds like a robot.

Comment: If you simply change the second one from *I would* to *I'd* it regains some of the normal conversational style, although I agree that the conjunction is most natural.